# Linear Programming - Showing optimality in a specific example (Section 2 - Problem 9 - Saul I. Gass)

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

The following linear program is a special case of the transportation problem (taken from  Linear Programming: Methods and Applications by Saul I. Gass‏):
[image]

It is not hard to guess that $x_{11}=5,x_{12}=0,x_{13}=0,x_{21}=3,x_{22}=5,x_{23}=2$ yields an optimal solution with objective value $26$. We are asked (in Problem 9) to prove that this solution is optimal.

> Suggested Solution:
> Assume towards a contradiction that this solution is not optimal, then either of $x_{12}$ or $x_{13}$ is positive. Assume without loss of generality that $x_{12}>0$ and define
> \begin{align*}
> y_{11}&=x_{11}+1 &y_{12}&=x_{12}-1 &y_{13}&=x_{13}\\
> y_{21}&=x_{21} - 1 &y_{22}&=x_{22}+1 &y_{23}&=x_{23}
> \end{align*}
> Note that $y$ is a feasible solution, and achieving objective value
> \begin{align*}
> c^Ty&=y_{11}+2y_{12}+4y_{13}+3y_{21}+2y_{22}+y_{23}\\
> &=\left(x_{11}+1\right)+2\left(x_{12}-1\right)+4x_{13}+3\left(x_{21}-1\right)+2\left(x_{22}+1\right)+x_{23}\\
> &=x_{11}+2x_{12}+4x_{13}+3x_{21}+2x_{22}+x_{23}-2\\
> &=c^Tx-2
> \end{align*}
> i.e., $c^Ty<c^Tx$, contradicting the optimality of $x$.

However, this solution seems to be very specific. So I wanted to ask maybe you have comments or suggestions for a more elegant solution. At this point in the book, the reader is not introduced to the notation of duality.

Nevertheless, if someone is interested in the dual:

> \begin{align*} &\max_{z\in\mathbb{R^5}} &5z_{1}+10z_{2}+8z_{3}+5z_{4}+2z_{5}\\ &\mathrm {s.b.t.} &z_{1}+z_{3}&\le1\\ & &z_{1}+z_{4}&\le2\\ & &z_{1}+z_{5}&\le4\\ & &z_{2}+z_{3}&\le3\\ & &z_{2}+z_{4}&\le2\\ & &z_{2}+z_{5}&\le1 \end{align*} taking $z_1=z_4=0,z_2=2,z_3=1,z_5=-1$ yields an optimal target value 26 (as promised by the strong duality theorem this equals the minimum value of the primal LP).

Comment: I don't understand the suggested solution. Assuming that $x$ is feasible then $y$ is not even feasible, it does not satisfy the $3$rd & $4$th constraints.

Comment: @copper.hat Nice catch, fixed thanks.

Comment: I still don't understand. you take the direction you have given $d=(1,-1,0,-1,1,0)^T$, then $x+5d$ is feasible and has a cost $10$ lower than the solution you describe as optimal.

Comment: @copper.hat The error is that the guessed solution has objective value $36$, not $26$.  Your suggested improvement is optimal.

Comment: @RobPratt I was trying the Socratic method :-).

Comment: @copper.hat Fair enough.  I should have let Plato reply. :)

Comment: @copper.hat thanks., I fixed the guessed solution.

Comment: Now use strong duality. Actually, weak duality suffices.

Comment: @copper.hat I did it (in the spoiler box), but for sure it was not the intent. I think the suggested solution was the Author's intentions. By the way, If you have an elegant way of solving the dual, share it, please.

Comment: I am not sure what counts as elegant. Note that the dual cost can be written as $5(z_1+z_3)+2(z_2+z_5)+5(z_2+z_4)+3(z_2+z_3)$ and replacing the parenthesised values by the corresponding constraint upper bound yields $26$. It is straightforward to check that $y=(-1,-1,1,1,1) $ spans $\ker A^T$ and $b^T y = 0$. In particular, **any** feasible solution has the same dual cost. A trial with the additional constraint $z_1 = 0$ forces the solution given in the answer above. Hence the optimal dual value is $26$.

Comment: @copper.hat How did you derive this dual cost?
If $A$ is the constraint's coefficients matrix then $A^T$ has rank $4$, so no particular vector can span $\mathbb{R}^4$. Can you clarify?

Comment: The dual cost can be grouped as $5(z_1+z_3)+2(z_2+z_5)+5(z_2+z_4)+3(z_2+z_3)$ and comparing the parenthesised parts with the corresponding constraints shows that $26$ is an upper bound for the dual cost. If this value is attained then it must be a solution. Setting the parenthesised parts equal to the corresponding constraints gives $4$ equations in $5$ unknowns. Adding the extra constraint $z_1 = 0$ results in a feasible solution that attains the dual cost of $26$.

Comment: @copper.hat How did you get this "grouped" dual cost?

Comment: @ProperIllumination Multiply each dual constraint by the corresponding variable in the optimal primal solution, and add them up.